# Implementing Neural Nets with Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, mnist

I am trying to implement this [code](https://github.com/ageron/tf2_course) in my computer, the problem I was facing is running the following code gives an error:

```
fashion_mnist = keras.datasets.fashion_mnist
(X_train_full, y_train_full), (X_test, y_test) = (fashion_mnist.load_data())
X_valid, X_train = X_train_full[:5000], X_train_full[5000:]
y_valid, y_train = y_train_full[:5000], y_train_full[5000:]
```

the error:

```
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\utils\data_utils.py in get_file(fname, origin, untar, md5_hash, file_hash, cache_subdir, hash_algorithm, extract, archive_format, cache_dir)
    251         urlretrieve(origin, fpath, dl_progress)
    252       except HTTPError as e:
--> 253         raise Exception(error_msg.format(origin, e.code, e.msg))
    254       except URLError as e:
    255         raise Exception(error_msg.format(origin, e.errno, e.reason))

Exception: URL fetch failure on https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/tf-keras-datasets/train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz: 403 -- Forbidden
```

but If I tried to download the data separately it does not give an error of Forbidden, I tried to load the data without downloading it from ***Google*** but got another error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-68fe7d0ac27a> in <module>
      1 fashion_mnist = keras.datasets.fashion_mnist
----> 2 (X_train_full, y_train_full), (X_test, y_test) = (fashion_mnist)
      3 X_valid, X_train = X_train_full[:5000], X_train_full[5000:]
      4 y_valid, y_train = y_train_full[:5000], y_train_full[5000:]

TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable module object
```

In the end, I decided not to use `load_data()` method but still the same error, Is there any way to unpack and prepare the data from *`train-labels-idx1-ubyte`* without using the above method?

PS: I tried using a VPN but still responding Forbidden

Comment: Which Keras version is this?

Comment: latest version `2.3.1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's downloaded correctly, you need to specify your path.

Have you tried `(X_train_full, y_train_full), (X_test, y_test) = fashion_mnist.load_data (path="%yourLocalPath%")` as documented [Here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/datasets/mnist/load_data?version=stable) ?
[tensorflow docs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78RBB.png)

If it's not, The first error you got because you live in a place where TensorFlow is Forbidden, simply just use a VPN.

Comment: As I mentioned before I used a VPN and checked the IP which was Austrian, I will check the Docs as you suggesting